# How to make HTTP request authenticated with anonymous NTLM using HttpWebRequest

Tags: c#, .net, httpwebrequest, ntlm, anonymous

My team recently discovered a bug in some of our service code, such that an HTTP request authenticated with the anonymous NTLM SID (**not** the same as HTTP Anonymous authentication; this is a successful NTLM authentication exchange that results in the Anonymous SID) was allowed to proceed when it should have been refused.  We've fixed the problem by examining the WindowsIdentity.IsAnonymous property, but I want to write an automated test for this case so we never have this problem again.

Which leads me to my problem.  I need to make an HTTP GET request to a particular URL, using HttpWebRequest or Microsoft.HttpClient, which authenticates via NTLM as the Anonymous SID.  So far the only way I can make this happen is to run the client code as LocalSystem; for obvious reasons, that's not ideal for our automated test regime.

I've tried this:

```
using (WindowsIdentity.GetAnonymous().Impersonate()) { 
    //Make HTTP request here, with UseDefaultCredentials = true
}
```

but Impersonate throws an exception indicating the anonymous token cannot be impersonated.

Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to set [UseDefaultCredentials](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.usedefaultcredentials.aspx) to false:

```
request.Credentials = null;
request.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to work.  I wrote a test that does that, and using Fiddler I can see the HTTP request it generates.  Instead of using NTLM with the anonymous token, it makes the HTTP client use no authentication, so when the server sends back an NTLM challenge the client gives up.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your distinction between "NTLM with the anonymous token" and "HTTP client use no authentication".  One of us is obviously confused about how the anonymous account works ;)